# getters not update value in Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, router

I don't understand how getters work in Vuex. **The problem is** when logging out the token in state and localStorage is becoming empty, but not in getters.
In `created` I call this:

```
created: async function () {
    if (this.$store.getters.shortToken) {
      this.isConfirm = true
    }
    console.log(
      'signining', localStorage.getItem('token'), // ''
      'state', this.$store.state.user.token, // ''
      'getter', this.$store.getters.token // 'old-token'
    )
    if (this.$store.getters.token) {
      await this.$router.push({ path: '/' })
    }
  }
```

And `getters` have:

```
token: state => {
    return localStorage.getItem('token') || state.user.token
  }
```

And `mutation`:

```
SET_TOKEN: (state, payload) => {
      localStorage.setItem('token', payload.token)
      Object.assign(state, payload)
    }
```

BUT, console log in created gives me empty localStorage token (which is normal) and empty state.token (which is also normal).. But, getters.token gives me token (which is NOT normal), because I gave SET_TOKEN empty token. Why is this happening?
**PS.** If I'm adding `console.log(state.user.token, localStorage.getItem('token'))` above `return` in getters token, so `getters.token` in `created` hook is empty... **WHY?**

 Also some using codes in this situation, this is logout method:

```
methods: {
    async logout () {
      if (await this.$store.dispatch('logOut')) {
        console.log('logged out')
        await this.$router.push({ path: '/signin' })
      }
    }
  }
```

action logout

```
async logOut (context) {
    console.log('logggog')
    context.commit('SET_TOKEN', {
      token: ''
    })
    context.commit('SET_USER', {
      user: null
    })
    return true
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Getters are meant to compute `derived state` based on `store state`.

You are facing this problem because you are returning the value of `localStorage.getItem()` from your `Getter`, which is not a value of the `store state`, thus it is not `reactive` nor `observable`.

In your example, Vuex will not recompute the value of the Getter when you call `localStorage.setItem()`.
It will recompute the Getter's value only when `state.user.token` is changed.

So, if you want to have the Getter working correctly, return just the value of `state.user.token`.
You can also add a `created` hook in your `App.vue` that would check if there is a token in the localStorage and call the `SET_TOKEN` mutation, if that is what you were trying to accomplish by calling `localStorage.getItem` in your Getter:

```
App.vue

<script>
    created() {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
        if (token != null) {
            this.$store.mutations.SET_TOKEN({ token });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Nonetheless, be aware of [change detection caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) when using `Object.assign`, because Vuex [mutations follow Vue's reactivity rules](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#mutations-follow-vue-s-reactivity-rules).

In your mutation you should probably do:

```
SET_TOKEN: (state, payload) => {
    localStorage.setItem('token', payload.token);
    state.token = payload.token;
}
```

or if `payload` is actually `state.user` you can do:

```
SET_TOKEN: (state, payload) => {
    localStorage.setItem('token', payload.token);
    state.user = {
       ...payload
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you.. I solved my problem a little bit another.. but your words about not reactively localStorage gives me an insight